# Kivy binding to on_property doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, binding, kivy

Essentially, I have a grid with squares, and I keep track of which squares are occupied with a BooleanProperty on each square. Here's a simplified version of all the places in my code I declare the "occupied" property:

```
class Board(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cols = 4
        self.grid = []
        self.create_slots()




    def create_slots(self):
        for i in range(10):
            self.grid.append([])
            for j in range(4):
                temp = Square(i,j, "sideboard")
                self.grid[i].append(temp)
                self.add_widget(temp)
                temp.bind(on_occupied = self.do_a_thing)


    def do_a_thing(self):
        for square in self.children:
            #do a thing

class Square(Button):
    def __init__(self, row, col, type):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.id = str(self.row) + "," + str(self.col)
        self.type = type
        self.occupied = BooleanProperty(False)
        super().__init__()
```

My goal is to bind the "do_a_thing" method to be called each time the value of the square's "occupied" property changes. Because the Square class is used elsewhere in my app, I don't want to set the callback for on_occupied in the kivy language, and I was hoping to avoid creating a Square sub-class just to change the one binding.

When I run my code, it throws no errors, and I've verified that the "occupied" property does actually change. But the "do_a_thing" method never gets fired. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Bind to `occupied` (I have made that mistake before)

Comment: hmmm, @zeeMonkeez, I tried that, but I'm getting this error: File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 438, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind (kivy/_event.c:6026)
 KeyError: 'occupied'

Comment: also, make sure you `self.add_widget(Square())` (an instance of `Square` rather than the class). Finally, `do_a_thing` should take 3 arguments.

Comment: Edited the code self.add_widget(Square()) (it's correct in my actual code, just not the simplified version I wrote for this question).      Can you clarify which arguments do_a_thing should take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for a property `my_property`, the change event is called `my_property` as well. The callback receives two arguments: [instance that fired the event, and new value of the property](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.bind), as shown in [the docs](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html#dispatching-a-property-event). Also, if the class has a method called `on_`*`propertyname`*, this will be called as well.
Here is a self-contained example that works for me:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty

class Board(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Board, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(10):
            self.add_widget(Square())
        for square in self.children:
            print square
            square.bind(occupied=self.do_a_thing)

    def do_a_thing(self, *args):
        print "hello from {}, new state: {}".format(*args)
        for square in self.children:
            pass
            #do a thing

class Square(Button):
     occupied = BooleanProperty(False)
     def on_occupied(self, *args):
         print "Callback defined in class: from {} state {}".format(*args)


class mApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string("""
Board:
    cols: 4
    rows: 3
<Square>:
    on_press: self.occupied = ~self.occupied
""")
mApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. I've edited my code as you suggested, even using your exact on_occupied method. However, when I bind to "occupied" I still get a KeyError (in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind (kivy/_event.c:6026) KeyError: 'occupied').  This does not happen if I try to bind to "on_occupied" (which of course, doesn't work).

Comment: @KSully2  Does this example run as is, though?

Comment: yes, your example runs fine. I've edited my code in the original question now since the error wasn't happening in the simpler snippet.

Comment: @KSully2 make sure `occupied` is defined as in my example (right after `class`), not in `__init__`.

Comment: that did it! I was under the impression that you couldn't define those properties *outside* of an __init__. Why can I have both that statement and the init?

Comment: @KSully2 See the [properties man page](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103236/discussion-between-ksully2-and-zeemonkeez).